# PHP array multisort (version 5/7 differences)

Tags: php

I got a array like this:

```
$json = '{"Categorie1":[{"created":"2017-07-17 08:53:00","catid":"54"},{"created":"2017-05-23 10:15:00","catid":"54"},{"created":"2017-05-09 05:49:23","catid":"54"}],"Categorie2":[{"created":"2017-03-21 08:58:37","catid":"59"},{"created":"2016-12-23 12:48:00","catid":"59"},{"created":"2016-12-08 09:57:10","catid":"59"}],"Categorie3":[],"Categorie4":[{"created":"2017-08-02 07:15:07","catid":"70"},{"created":"2017-08-01 08:03:00","catid":"70"},{"created":"2017-07-31 09:25:00","catid":"70"}],"Categorie5":[{"created":"2017-07-26 14:09:00","catid":"74"},{"created":"2017-06-29 14:03:00","catid":"74"},{"created":"2017-06-28 06:35:35","catid":"74"}]}';
```

And I wrote a sorting function. Basically it checks which block (categorie) got the newest entry and brings that block to top, sort the blocks):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
function custom($a, $b) {    
    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($b[$k])) {
            return (strtotime($a[$k]["created"]) <= strtotime($b[$k]["created"]));
        }
    }
}
uasort($array, "custom");
```

When I print this with PHP 5 its perfect: Categorie4 is the first block". But with PHP 7 it doesn't.

```
print("<pre>");
print_r($array); // PHP 5 is as expected, php 7 is not
```

I know there where changes, but I can't figure out how to change my code.
Can you guys helping me change the code? The result should show categorie4 as first cat...

Comment: "Categorie3" is empty. Where should it stay in the output? Currently it is in the middle of the "sorted" array and it doesn't make any sense. What is the sorting rule?

Comment: The comparison function is completely wrong. It should return an integer value that for descending order is `<0` when `$a>$b`, `0` when `$a==$b` or `>0` when `$a<$b`. Yours return `TRUE` (converted by PHP to `1`) when `$a<=$b` and `FALSE` (`0`) when `$a>$b`.

Comment: @AlivetoDie that output **is not** sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function used by the [user-defined array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) must return an integer value that is `<0` if `$a < $b`, `0` when `$a == $b` or `>0` when `$a > $b`. Yours return a boolean that is converted to `1` or `0` and that doesn't reflect the correct order of `$a` and `$b`.

It's not clear from the question how should be sorted the empty entries (`Categorie3`) and I think their place is at the end.

Try this code for PHP 5:

```
uasort($array, function (array $a, array $b) {
    if (empty($a)) { return +1; }    // empty arrays go to the end of the list
    if (empty($b)) { return -1; }
    return strcmp($a[0]['created'], $b[0]['created']);
});
```

The date&time values of `created` use a format that can be sorted directly as strings, there is no need to convert them to timestamps.

In PHP 7 you can use the new [`<=>` comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) that, in theory, should run faster than the [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function while it produces the same result.

```
uasort($array, function (array $a, array $b) {
    if (empty($a)) { return +1; }    // empty arrays go to the end of the list
    if (empty($b)) { return -1; }
    return $b[0]['created'] <=> $a[0]['created'];
});
```

Comment: Great, that works. One question, since im dealing with a date should i use strtotime instead?:  return strtotime($b[0]['created']) <=> strtotime($a[0]['created']);

Comment: I already answered to that in the answer. If you are sure the values of `created` always have the format `Y-m-d H:i:s` then there is no need to use `strtotime()` because this format keeps the order of the date&time values it represents.